# Unable to set property 'ajaxEnabled' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-5

I have developed a website for PC using asp.net MVC5. Now trying to develop a mobile supported anonymous access web page for same website using asp.net MVC5. I created a new project for this and downloaded jQuery.Mobile.MVC from Nuget console. This added mobile layout in the project with the JS code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
});
```

I just added a new view with this mobile layout and added few label controls to see how it works. It throws below error

JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'ajaxEnabled' of undefined or null reference

Do I have to add any other libraries? This is my first mobile page. It would be great if you are help with some good tutorials

I have included jquery.mobile.js references

Thanks

Comment: Is the `jquery.mobile.js` definitely loaded in the page, or did you just download the nuget package?  Is your script which is referencing `$.mobile` happening **after** the `jquery.mobile.js` is loaded in the page?

Comment: jquery.mobile.js reference has been included in the layout page  before loading the script @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a conflict with the version of jQuery.

To get this working using the nuget package change your code to the following:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")"></script>
<script>
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jq(function () {
        jq.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
```

However I would recommend not using the nuget package and install the latest versions manually.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jquery and jquery.mobile js scripts yet? Adding this into document ready and see whether or not it is working.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Comment: I have included reference. I should have mentioned this also in my question. Edited now